# what is the difference between below regex in terms of time complexity

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
Regex_Pattern = r"^\d\w{4}\.$"
Regex_Pattern = r"^[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]{4}[.]{1}$"
print(str(bool(re.search(Regex_Pattern, raw_input()))).lower())
```

I get different execution time for both the regex exp. first one gets executed faster than second .
Input 0qwer.

Comment: please include the code that you use to do the testing and the results

Answer (score 3):

Testing your regexes on [regex101](https://regex101.com/#python) site reveals that both of them take `6 steps` to find a match. So they're really the same. The reason the first is running faster than the second probably has to do with the mere fact that the first string is shorter; a bit less time to parse and compile.

Try compiling the regexes first separately by creating a regex object `sequence = regex.compile(r'regexhere', flags)` and then calling its search method `sequence.search(test_subject)`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually `\d` and `[0-9]` are equal as well as `\w` and `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. The only difference is using `[.]{1}` (which `{1}` is redundant) over `\.` that it doesn't make much difference in terms of runtime.